# how can i restructure the data frame in R

Tags: r, pivot, reshape2

I have the following df:

```
>df
      cluster_no days_to_port             channel
1          1          2.8                 MMR
2          2          4.1 Spark Retail Stores
3          3          2.4 Spark Retail Stores
4          4          3.0 Spark Retail Stores
5          5          3.5 Spark Retail Stores
             channel_outlet_name             region
1 PIN Distributor Ltd (Activata) Auckland - Central
2   Spark - Auckland Int Airport            Mangere
3   Spark - Auckland Int Airport            Mangere
4   Spark - Auckland Int Airport            Mangere
5   Spark - Auckland Int Airport            Mangere
```

I am trying to reshape/pivot this into the below format so that i could do some further conditional formatting and analysis: (so columns are cluster numbers and rows are the variables)

```
cluster_no           1    2     3    4   5
days_to_port                    
channel                 
channel_outlet_name                 
region
```

I could achieve using pivot in excel:

[image]

I would like to achieve the same using R.(BTW numeric values in df are mean values and categorical values are mode)

Comment: What are the values in the expected output?

Comment: t(df) although this will not maintain the class of the variables

Comment: Transposing doesnt give me the structure i am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(cluster=1:5,
                 days_to_port=c(2.8,4.1,2.4,3.0,3.5),
                 channel=c('MMR','Spark Retail Stores','Spark Retail Stores','Spark Retail Stores','Spark Retail Stores'),
                 channel_outlet_name=c('PIN Distributor Ltd (Activata)','Spark - Auckland Int Airport','Spark - Auckland Int Airport','Spark - Auckland Int Airport','Spark - Auckland Int Airport'),
                 region=c('Auckland - Central','Mangere','Mangere','Mangere','Mangere'))

library(tidyr)
out <- df %>% gather(key=key,value=value,-cluster) %>%
  spread(cluster,value)

out
                  key                              1                            2                            3                            4                            5
1             channel                            MMR          Spark Retail Stores          Spark Retail Stores          Spark Retail Stores          Spark Retail Stores
2 channel_outlet_name PIN Distributor Ltd (Activata) Spark - Auckland Int Airport Spark - Auckland Int Airport Spark - Auckland Int Airport Spark - Auckland Int Airport
3        days_to_port                            2.8                          4.1                          2.4                            3                          3.5
4              region             Auckland - Central                      Mangere                      Mangere                      Mangere                      Mangere
```

Comment: Fantastic..This is what i was looking for.